# How to add a vertical line at a specific datapoint in WPF Toolkit Chart

Tags: wpf, charts, toolkit

I have created a multi series line chart but I need to add a vertical line marker at the beginning and at the end of a cycle. I have researched everywhere and can't find how to do it.  I need to do it from code behind because the value changes with every chart.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to add a vertical line was to add a datapoint at a specific x and y value.  Notice that the two datapoints have the same X value.  One starts at y value of 100 and the other one at 1200 thus making it a straight vertical line.

```
            //******************************************************
        //This is for plotting vertical lines
        //******************************************************
        lsStartCycle.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
        lsStartCycle.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");

        lsStartCycle.ItemsSource = new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>[]
        {
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(MyFunctions.StartCycleTime, 100),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(MyFunctions.StartCycleTime, 1200) };
```

In XAML I added a new series.

```
                <DVC:LineSeries Name="lsStartCycle" Title="Cycle Start"    
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        DataPointStyle="{StaticResource myLineDataPointStyle}"
                        PolylineStyle="{StaticResource DashedPolyLine}"
                        LegendItemStyle="{StaticResource HideLegend}"
                        IsSelectionEnabled="True">
                </DVC:LineSeries>
```

Note:  My advice is to stay away from WPF Toolkit Chart.  Use the MS Chart control instead, it is way way better.  I ended up using that chart instead.